# Flutter - Efficiency of Positioned widgets in a Stack

Tags: flutter

Depending on the use case, Positioned widgets can find themselves rendering outside the bounds of a Stack. A Stack has the field `overflow`, which when set to `Overflow.clip` causes widgets outside the Stack to not paint.

Is this `Overflow.clip` a substitute for determining whether or not a Positioned widget should be added to a list of children for the Stack? Or are there a noticeable performance degradation (assuming there are potentially hundreds of widgets being drawn off screen)?

If `Overflow.clip` is not sufficient, is there a way to determine if a Positioned widget will exceed the bounds of its Stack?

In my particular use case, I have a Stack with the first child being a canvas widget (that renders an isometric grid where widgets can be placed on top of tiles). With my pan and zoom implemented, some tiles can be off the screen. The goal is to not even add widgets that would be rendered off screen.

Comment: To begin with, you should **never** have overflow. Never.

Comment: **efficiency** doesn't have the same meaning as **sufficiency**. You can measure and calculate your widgets after layout rendered

Comment: In theory, my canvas renderer can support an untold amount of tiles. It's efficient and only renders tiles that would be visible. What I'm trying to do is allow mounting flutter widgets via the Positioned widget. What I don't want to do is create Positioned widgets that wouldn't even be visible. Furthermore, I have already implemented pan and zoom for the canvas renderer using the scale gesture and Canvas.translate and Canvas.Scale